# Accessing a class value in another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# MenuItem.py
class MenuItem:
    def __init__(self, name=None, types=None, price=None, description=None):
        self._name = name
        self._types = types
        self._price = price
        self._description = description
```

```
# Diner.py
class Diner(object):
    STATUS = ["seated", "ordering", "eating", "paying", "leaving"]
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name
        self.__order = []
        self.__status = self.STATUS[0]
    def __str__(self):
        return ('Diner {} is currently {}'.format(self.__name, self.__status))
def calculateMealCost(self):
        for value, key in enumerate(self.__order):
            return MenuItem[value].price
```

I got 2 python files MenuItems.py and Diner.py. I want the calculateMealCost() method to return the total meal cost of a particular diner but when I do this

```
def calculateMealCost(self):
        for value, key in enumerate(self.__order):
            return MenuItem[value].price
```

I get this error message:

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

How can I hack my way around this, please?

Comment: `MenuItem` is a class. You need to create an object of that type. And in your case a list of `MenuItem` objects.

Comment: Why do you think `MenuUtem[value]` is supposed to do? You probably want `key.price` but you need to actually provide the calling code. `key` is a strange name here, and it looks like you don't need `enumerate` at all...

Comment: you don'y need to "hack" anything. You simply need to make your code make sense. Right now you are trying to access the `value` element of the type `MenuItem`

Comment: Where are you defining the items and prices? Your code doesn't work because you can't normally subscript a type.

Comment: You don't want class attributes here. I think `self__order` should be a list of instances of `MenuItem`.

Comment: Also why are you putting a `return` statement inside a loop? Your loop will **always** iterate exactly once...

Answer (score 0):

If the two classes are in different files, supposing that they are in the same directory, then you are missing an import statement:

```
from MenuItem import MenuItem
```

Now, in order to access the price instance attribute that you want to access you need to have an instance of the class MenuItem already configured:

```
chocolate_pie = MenuItem(price=3)
```

Then and only then can you ask for the price of the chocolate pie:

```
print(chocolate_pie.price)
```

In other words, if I understand your code correctly, you need to have defined all items on the menu as instances of the class MenuItem first and then you will be able to access the price attribute of each item on the menu to add the prices together to get your final meal cost